# Apache Archiva file upload size

Tags: repository, archiva

If I upload an artifact (~23MB file size) in Apache-Archiva 2.2.1, I get an upload-error in the UI:

> fileupload.errors.Request Entity Too Large

This occurs also with mvn deploy:

> Return code is: 413, ReasonPhrase: Request Entity Too Large

Archiva is running on tomcat 9.0.0.M21, deployed as war.

So, how can I increase the upload file size limit in apache archiva? I can't find any appropriate properties to set in archiva.xml.

Answer (score 2):

So finally i could resolve this problem. It was not an Archiva setting, increasing the upload size in nginx.conf to `client_max_body_size 64M;` fixed it (Tomcat is running behind a SSL-Proxy).

Thx for watching.